# WPF Resources - Shared?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

As I know button does not create new instance, it uses shared resource.
Why is button's background blue and not Red?

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Name="st">
        <Button Margin="50" Name="btn" Height="50">Click</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
st.Resources.Add("Back", Brushes.Blue);
       btn.Background = (Brush)btn.TryFindResource("Back");
       st.Resources["Back"] = Brushes.Red;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once setting the `Background`, it's just kind of snapshotting. Changing the Resource after that won't change the `Background`. You have to use some kind of setting resource reference using `SetResourceReference` method like this:

```
st.Resources.Add("Back", Brushes.Blue);                
btn.SetResourceReference(Control.BackgroundProperty, "Back");
st.Resources["Back"] = Brushes.Red;
```